# Get corresponding value to dropdown Boolean

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to make a spreadsheet where I can enter an amount and then select if that amount was paid or not. If it was paid, the corresponding value should be added to `C2`. If it was not paid, the corresponding value should be added to `D2`.

I would like to know how to write the formulas to get the following outputs in `C2` and `D2`.

[image: sheet]

Just to clarify, the values in `C2` and `D2` shown in the screenshot were manually entered and are not tied to any formula.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You need `=SUMIF(B2:B,"Paid",A2:A)` and `=SUMIF(B2:B,"Not Paid",A2:A)` for cell C2 and D2 respectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `C1` you need:

```
=SUMIF(B2:B,”NO”,A2:A)
```

In `D1` you need:

```
=SUMIF(B2:B,”YES”,A2:A)
```